# Applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem for the sequence $\int _0^1 \frac{n e^{-x}}{(1+nx)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have a simple enough limit of the integral of a sequence of functions given by:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{n e^{-x}}{(1+nx)^2}dx
$$
It is clear that $\frac{n}{(1+nx)^2}$ is decreasing in $n$ so we have:
$$
\left|\frac{n e^{-x}}{(1+nx)^2}\right|  \leq \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}
$$
and $ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}=1/2$. So DCT applies and we have:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{n e^{-x}}{(1+nx)^2} dx =  \int_0^1 \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n e^{-x}}{(1+nx)^2}dx=0$$
But this is wrong, as can be seen through direct integration by MATHEMATICA which gives:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{n e^{-x}}{(1+nx)^2} dx = 1$$
where am I making the mistake.

**EDIT**
As one of the commentators pointed, $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ is not a dominating function for $f_n(x) = \frac{n e^{-x}}{(1+nx)^2}$, for the simple reason that at $x=0$, $f_n = n$.
Instead, I attempt to use the substitution $y=nx$ to transform the integral into:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{n e^{-x}}{(1+nx)^2}dx =\int_0^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{[0, n]}(y)\frac{e^{-y/n}}{(1+y)^2}dy
$$
It is clear that $f_n(y) = \mathbf{1}_{[0, n]}(y)\frac{e^{-y/n}}{(1+y)^2} \nearrow \frac{1}{(1+y)^2}$, giving the result through the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Is this correct?

[[image: behaviour of <span class=]$f_n$ on [0,1]" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZhaF.png)

Comment: $\left|\frac{n e^{-x}}{(1+nx)^2}\right|  \leq \frac{n}{(1+nx)^2}$ would better and gives the result.

Comment: Should not the dominating function independent of $n$? (in the condition for the Dominated Convergence Theorem)

Comment: Check the behavior of the integrand at $x=0$. What you claim is a dominating function is not correct.

Comment: Yes, I see now. How can I obtain a dominating function? does the substation $y = nx$ work?

Comment: I think the above substitution works together with the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Yes it does ...

Comment: Do you now see why your original assertion that the integrand is decreasing in $n$ is false for all $x \in [0,1]$? I believe the question was “where am I making a mistake?”

Comment: yes, I saw where the mistake is. I wrote it in the edit.

Comment: @Iconoclast Your new approach works

Comment: @Iconoclast For your EDIT, we can use the DCT even if $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ is not a dominating function at $x=0$. In fact, if this is the only reason, $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ remains a dominating function $\lambda$-a.e.

Comment: Houssam the behavior at zero is not the only reason. See the plots I have attached in the new edit